# Как объединить два запроса sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

Есть таблица sqlite

```
tabl1
```

в ней поля

```
name, exp
```

Надо, чтобы сначала вывелись строки в которых exp=0, а под ней строки, где exp=1 и упорядочено было по имени. Результат должен быть например таким:

```
name:Alex exp:0
name:Boris exp:0
name:Veron exp:0

name:Alexandr exp:1
name:Evgeniy exp:1
name:Veron exp:1
```

я пробую вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT name, exp FROM tbl1 WHERE exp=0 UNION SELECT name, exp FROM tbl1 WHERE exp=1 ORDER by name
```

Выборка происходит, но перемешаны значения с exp=0 и exp=1,
а мне надо чтобы сверху шли строки где exp=0, а под ними строки где exp=1 и расположены в алфавитном порядке первые строки (где exp=0), а затем вторые (где exp=1).
Как должен выглядеть запрос?

Comment: Порядок сортировки указывается только в order by, следовательно единственный путь это `order by exp, name` и union тут кстати вообще не нужен достаточно `where exp in(0,1)`

Comment: Mike, спасибо, твой ответ мне реально помог!